# Asynchronous Sequential Chains in Langchain

Tags: openai-api, langchain, py-langchain

I have a code meant to take a product review, extract a sentiment and put it in another prompt. When I do it asynchronously, I get illogical answers. What is the best way to fix it such that for each review it extracts the sentiment and uses the sentiment as input to another chain which then generates a new sentence for each review?

```py
async def async_generate(chain, review_text):
    resp = await chain.arun({'review_text':review_text})
    return resp

async def generate_concurrently():
    llm = OpenAI(temperature=0.9)
    prompt_a = PromptTemplate(input_variables=["review_text"], template=prompt_template_a,)
    prompt_b = PromptTemplate(input_variables=["a_output"], template=prompt_template_b,)
    a_chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=prompt_a, output_key="a_output")
    b_chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=prompt_b, output_key="b_output")
    chain = SequentialChain(chains=[a_chain, b_chain], input_variables=['review_text'],)
    tasks = [async_generate(chain, review_text) for review_text in reviews]
    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return results
```

I expected to get the final sentence for each review but it got jumbled up with sentence of review 1 being included in say review 10